# Why does Chrome have much better performance in rendering 3D graphics than Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, performance, graphics

I used the models in this [website](http://www.sketchfab.com) to test the performance of my computer to render 3D graphics, and I found that dragging a 3D model is very choppy in Safari, while in Chrome it’s much more fluid. I know little about how a computer works, but I’m curious about the reason for this difference.

Device information: MacBook Pro 15" Retina, 2015

macOS version: 10.13.1

**Edits:**
It turns out that the low performance of Safari in rendering 3D graphics has to do with the computer not being shut down for a long time. And suggested by Jake3231 in the comments, I used EtreCheck to check my computer. Here is the report:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am using a 2015 13" MacBook Pro with Safari 11 on macOS Sierra, and rendering performance is perfectly fine for me. Admittedly, the rest of the system does slow down while viewing a model. Have you tried restarting your system, then only opening Safari to that website?

Comment: @Jake3231 I just restarted the computer, and viewing the images in Safari (normal screen) becomes fluid indeed. Why is that? Another difference from yesterday's situation is that now I can hear the fan's noise in full screen view while it was very quiet yesterday.

Comment: My guess is that you may have had a lot of applications, or even one process, running in the background that was using a lot of your CPU. Do you restart, or at least quit programs, often?

Comment: @Jake3231 I guess I hadn't restarted the computer for a week. I opened the activity monitor yesterday, but there seems no other application that was consuming lots of cpu.

Comment: To help troubleshoot this, can you download EtreCheck at the following link and update your question with the results? https://etrecheck.com

Comment: @Jake3231 I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, the Etrecheck report looks pretty good. I would suggest that you remove the adware it found, as that can sometimes affect performance. You could click the red "remove" button next to items that are labeled as adware.

An alternative way to remove adware is by downloading [Malwarebytes for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/). After you do that, I would also suggest you update Flash Player just to protect against malware that may reduce browsing performance, among other things.

I would suggest that after this you also boot your Mac in Safe Mode. Once your system boots and displays a red "Safe Mode" label at the top right of the login screen, you can shut down and power on the machine. After that, hopefully things run a bit better. You can learn more about safe mode here: [Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)

Comment: Of course! Let me know how that works for you!